# View images from blob - sqlite

Tags: linux, database, macos, sqlite, blob

I have an sqlite file. It has a table that stores images as BLOBs.
What is the easiest way to see the images stored in the table?
Doing this:
`$sqlite3 mydb 'select(img) from image_table where id=“1”’ > image.png`
The `image.png` does not open on double click.

I tried also:

```
sqlite3 my.db "SELECT writefile('object0.gz', MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1"
```

but I am not sure how to open the `object0.gz` file. When I double click it the archive tool opens

Comment: That command produces text output.

Comment: @Ben: 1) I need to see all the rows in the table not just one 2) I tried the `sqlite3 m.db 'SELECT writefile("/proc/self/fd/1", img) FROM t WHERE id = 1;' > image.png` and when I double click on the `image.png` the file still doesn't open

Comment: @Ben: I tried the `sqlite3 my.db "SELECT writefile('object0.gz', MyBlob) FROM MyTable WHERE id = 1"` as the answer but how can I open the `object0.gz`?

Comment: Please click `edit` under your original question and add code & details there rather than in comments where the formatting is hard to read.

Comment: @Jim, the answer is on the linked question, first answer. "With SQLite 3.8.6 or later, the command-line shell includes the fileio extension, which implements the writefile function"

Comment: @MarkSetchell:Updated OP

Comment: @Ben: But the file does not open as an image. Please see updated OP

Comment: Jim, of course it doesn't open as an image! It is text. Read the other question - the one this duplicates.

Comment: How should the OS know that the file is an image when you give it a different extension?

Comment: How did you put the image into the database?

Comment: @CL.: When I do `f$ile object0.gz` I get: `file object0.gz 
object0.gz: JPEG image data, JFIF standard 1.01`

Comment: @MarkSetchell:See previous comment

Comment: @Ben:No, please see my comment to CL

Comment: @CL.:I changed the extension and it opened